# WinSock: 10038 - WSAENOTSOCK An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: delphi, winsock, delphi-10-seattle

Well i have this code where i'm trying receive data from client but happens that `GetLastError()` is returning:

> **10038** - `WSAENOTSOCK` *An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.*

I suspect that this trouble is related with the casting `Pointer` to `TSocket`, already that **`ClientThread()`** function below receives the socket througth your parameter.

How this can be solved?

```
const
 Buffer: array [0 .. 9] of AnsiChar = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
    'H', 'I', #0);

function ClientThread(P: Pointer): Integer;
var
  Buf: array [0 .. SizeOf(Buffer) - 1] of AnsiChar;
  Sock: TSocket;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Writeln('New thread started.' + #13#10);

  Sock := TSocket(P);

  if recv(Sock, Buf, SizeOf(Buffer), 0) <= 0 then //My trouble is here.
  begin
    Writeln(GetLastError);
    closesocket(Sock);
    Result := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

  if not CompareMem(@Buf, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)) then
  begin
    closesocket(Sock);
    Result := 0;
    Exit;
  end;

 end;

function StartServer(Port: Integer): Boolean;
var
  _wsdata: WSAData;
  serverSocket, S: TSocket;
  _addrIn, _addr: sockaddr_in;
  addrSize: Integer;
  tid: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;

  if WSAStartup(MakeWord(2, 2), _wsdata) <> 0 then
    Exit;

  serverSocket := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if serverSocket = INVALID_SOCKET then
    Exit;

  _addrIn.sin_family := AF_INET;
  _addrIn.sin_addr.S_addr := INADDR_ANY;
  _addrIn.sin_port := htons(Port);

  if bind(serverSocket, _addrIn, SizeOf(_addrIn)) = SOCKET_ERROR then
    Exit;

  if listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) = SOCKET_ERROR then
    Exit;

  addrSize := SizeOf(_addrIn);
  getsockname(serverSocket, _addrIn, addrSize);

  Writeln(Format('Listening on port %d' + #13#10, [ntohs(_addrIn.sin_port)]));

  while True do
  begin
    S := accept(serverSocket, @_addr, @addrSize);
    CreateThread(nil, 0, @ClientThread, @S, 0, tid);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

**Usage:**

```
StartServer(1234);
```

Comment: ThreadProc is stdcall. -  Sock := TSocket(P); -> Sock := TSocket(P^);

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, is **stdcall** only to pass parameter or **stdcall** is mandatory in any case?

Comment: @BrowJr `stdcall` is mandatory in this case because that is what `CreateThread()` requires. Is there a reason why you are using `CreateThread()` directly and not `TThread`? Or using Winsock directly instead of an existing wrapper, like `TServerSocket` or `TIdTCPServer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making several mistakes.

- The signature of your `ClientThread()` is wrong. It must be defined like this instead:

  ```
  function ClientThread(P: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
  ```

  Without the `stdcall`, the `P` parameter will not be passed in correctly.
- you are passing a *pointer* to a local `TSocket` variable to your threads.  In your `ClientThread()`, you are not dereferencing that pointer to access the original `TSocket`, which is what is causing your error message.

  But more importantly, you are reusing the same `TSocket` variable for multiple client threads. All of your threads are pointing to the same physical `TSocket`. Don't use the `@` operator, pass a *copy* of the  `TSocket` to each client thread.  Fortunately, `TSocket` is just a `UINT`, its value will fit as-is inside of a pointer.

  And you need to close that `TSocket` before the thread exits. You are not calling `closesocket()` if `CompareMem()` returns true.
- you are leaking threads, as you never close the `THandle` returned by `CreateThread()`.

With that said, try this instead:

```
const
  Buffer: array [0 .. 9] of AnsiChar = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', #0);

function ClientThread(P: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  Buf: array [0 .. SizeOf(Buffer) - 1] of AnsiChar;
  Sock: TSocket;
  Ret, NumRead: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Sock := TSocket(P);
  try
    WriteLn('New thread started.');
    NumRead := 0;
    repeat
      Ret := recv(Sock, @Buf[NumRead], SizeOf(Buffer)-NumRead, 0);
      if Ret <= 0 then
      begin
        if Ret = SOCKET_ERROR then
        begin
          Ret := WSAGetLastError;
          Writeln('recv error: ', Ret);
        end;
        Exit;
      end;
      Inc(NumRead, Ret);
    until NumRead = Sizeof(Buffer);

    if not CompareMem(@Buf, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)) then
    begin
      WriteLn('Buf does not match Buffer');
      Exit;
    end;

    WriteLn('Buf matches Buffer');
  finally
    closesocket(Sock);
  end;
end;

function StartServer(Port: Integer): Boolean;
var
  _wsdata: WSAData;
  serverSocket, S: TSocket;
  _addrIn, _addr: sockaddr_in;
  addrSize, Ret: Integer;
  tid: Cardinal;
  h: THandle;
begin
  Result := False;

  Ret := WSAStartup(MakeWord(2, 2), _wsdata);
  if Ret <> 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('WSAStartup error: ', Ret);
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    serverSocket := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if serverSocket = INVALID_SOCKET then
    begin
      Ret := WSAGetLastError;
      WriteLn('socket error: ', Ret);
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      _addrIn.sin_family := AF_INET;
      _addrIn.sin_addr.S_addr := INADDR_ANY;
      _addrIn.sin_port := htons(Port);

      if bind(serverSocket, _addrIn, SizeOf(_addrIn)) = SOCKET_ERROR then
      begin
        Ret := WSAGetLastError;
        WriteLn('bind error: ', Ret);
        Exit;
      end;

      if listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) = SOCKET_ERROR then
      begin
        Ret := WSAGetLastError;
        WriteLn('listen error: ', Ret);
        Exit;
      end;

      addrSize := SizeOf(_addrIn);
      getsockname(serverSocket, _addrIn, addrSize);
      WriteLn('Listening on port ', ntohs(_addrIn.sin_port));

      while True do
      begin
        addrSize := SizeOf(_addr);
        S := accept(serverSocket, @_addr, @addrSize);
        if S <> INVALID_SOCKET then
        begin
          WriteLn('Client connected.');
          h := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ClientThread, Pointer(S), 0, tid);
          if h = 0 then
          begin
            Ret := GetLastError;
            closesocket(S);
            WriteLn('CreateThread error: ', Ret);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      closesocket(serverSocket);
    end;
  finally
    WSACleanup;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: On line Ret := recv(Sock, @Buf[NumRead], SizeOf(Buffer)-NumRead, 0);
i get error "Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter"

Comment: @icinemagr there is no "constant object" in that line, unless you are passing `Buffer` instead of `Buf`. Also, the use of `@` expects the 2nd parameter to be a Pointer (as it is defined in the actual API), but if it is a `var` instead on your system then drop the `@`: `Ret := recv(Sock, Buf[NumRead], SizeOf(Buffer)-NumRead, 0);`